# Yii :My view file does not opens on ajax call

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a button in my form .i am passing some parameters to another form on button click.

My code is

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('newForm',"",  
array('class'=>'btn btn-success',
     'onclick'=>'test()'
    ));?>
```

My js code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function test(){
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('company/registration'); ?>',
        data:{ids:values},
        success:function(data){ 
         }
       error: function(data) { 
          alert("Error occured.please try again");
        }
    });
   </script>
```

My controller code is:

```
public function actionRegistration()
{
 $arrList=array();
 $arrList=$_POST;
 $model=new Registration;
 $this->render('_newRegistration',array('model'=>$model,));

}
```

Here my view doesnot open.What is problem with my code???

Comment: check what you obtain in success .. data  .. could be the  render code .....

Comment: when i alert data on success, the alert box opens .There code from the form to be opened gets displayed.

Comment: TRy alert(data) and you understand ..

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, this few things does matter
1.Do you want open  another file in modal popup (bootstrap)?
2.And in your controller you should use renderPartial instead of render.
3.and in your ajax success function you should render the data to the modal popup body
so your code in controller something like .

```
public function actionRegistration()
{
 $arrList=array();
 $arrList=$_POST;
 $model=new Registration;
 $this->renderPartial('_newRegistration',array('model'=>$model));

}
```

and in your ajax success function (if you are using modal popup),then your code something like

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('company/registration'); ?>',
        data:{ids:values},
        success:function(data){ 
             $("#your_modal_popup_id").html(data);//bootstrap modal popup
             $("#your_modal_popup_id").modal('show');//bootstrap modal popup  
         }
       error: function(data) { 
          alert("Error occured.please try again");
        }
    });
```

hope this help you

Comment: Here i dont want to open my form in dialog.How can this be done

Comment: so you want to open in some other div tag or somewhere else in the same page?

Comment: then why you are using ajax for it in  CHtml you can do this.e.g CHtml::link('newForm',array('controller/action','param1'=>'value'),array('class'=>'btn btn-success')); param1 if you want send the param in action

Comment: if you do not want to show the parameter in url then create $_SESSION.because in ajax also you can see the parameter with url.e.g Yii::app()->user->setState("state_name", "value"); and then get it by e.g. Yii::app()->user->getState("state_name");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104965/discussion-between-virendra-gawade-and-mani-ratna).